# Solution for multiple people working on one file GIT

Tags: git, github

I am newbie to git and have been working on a project where 3 people have to work on the same file parallel y.
is there any GIT command which could merge all the 3 peoples works who are working in same file without any conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any GIT command which could merge all the 3 peoples works who are working in same file without any conflict?

Git has no understanding of what its merging. Git can merge changes to different parts of a file, but if you try to merge two branches which change the same lines (or adjacent lines) Git needs a human to tell it which changes to pick.

Conflicts are a normal part of the merge process, but they can be reduced. How depends on the circumstances. Generally, avoid long lived branches with sprawling changes. Keep branches short and focused by following the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).